# Python multiprocess does not work or throw exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a class and in constructor i am creating objects of Process class as below

```
self.child = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.load_paths,args = (self.paths,self.queue,))
self.child.daemon = True
```

In a separate function i try to start the process like

```
def start_child(self):
    self.child.start()
    print 'child started'
```

now whenever i call the function start_child() 3rd time or n+2th time, the child is started but message is never printed and call is not returned.

Edit: The process which is starting the new children is also a child process started by some other process.

This does not return any exception and works exactly as expected in windows(python 2.7.8). 
The problem arises in Ubuntu with python 2.7.6

How can i mitigate it provided the task manager does not show any anomaly in windows for this code?

Comment: which message are you talking about that is not printed? `print 'child started'`?

Comment: yes the print 'child started'

Comment: By " The process which is starting the new children is also a child process started by some other process", do you mean 'start_child', is also started by some other process?

Comment: yes, that is what i meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by inheriting target class from `multiprocessing.Process` and overriding the run function.